# Checkbox and radio doesn't work as expected when checking

Tags: c#, winforms

I have application where i am trying to make checkbox checked based on value i get from string. String name is called **aktivan** and returns values **Da** or **Ne**, i checked with messagebox and values are here and valid. If value are **Da** it need to check checkbox but it doesn't work.

```
chkAktivan.Checked = aktivan == "Da" ? true : false; // doesn't work
chkAktivan.Checked = true; // working
chkAktivan.Checked = false; // working
```

Same is for radio, based on string values `Muški` or `Ženski` it need to set values but also does't working all time its checking `Ženski` radio.

```
if (spol == "Muški")
{
    radioMuski.Checked = true;
    radioZenski.Checked = false;
}
else
{
    radioMuski.Checked = false;
    radioZenski.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the radio buttons in a GroupBox?

Comment: Hi! What method is your code in? There are some event handlers in Windows Forms that are triggered on various user interactions with the form.  You should attach any initialization logic in a method that is triggered when the form loads.  If you are pulling data from a repository, please ensure that this UI logic is after the data is loaded.

Comment: @jdweng buttons are not in gropbox they are in normal panel. Glenn Ferrie i am sending code from one form datagidView from selected user into user control page where i am populating form textboxes, but there is no issue with sending and getting data because i checked all data before and after i try to check checkbox or radio and values are not missing, and all textboxes and comboxes are filled just those 2 don't want to work i don't know why.

Comment: If this is within the row of a datagridview then a different set of rules apply.  Waiting on updated code sample.

Comment: @preciousbetine thanks i forgot to Trim() now all working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should trim the values before using them, like this.

```
if (spol.Trim() == "Muški")
{
    radioMuski.Checked = true;
    radioZenski.Checked = false;
}
else
{
    radioMuski.Checked = false;
    radioZenski.Checked = true;
}
```

And also this.

```
chkAktivan.Checked = aktivan == "Da" ? true : false;
```

To this:

```
chkAktivan.Checked = aktivan.Trim() == "Da" ? true : false;
```

Comment: Change it to `if (spol.Trim() == "Muški") ` and also `chkAktivan.Checked = aktivan.Trim() == "Da" ? true : false;` then i will accept answer, since incoming values need to be Trim() -ed.

Comment: Thanks, just to note first line isn't good, no need to trim string value inside of " " change it please to `if (spol.Trim() == "Muški")` only "spol" need to be Trim() -ed

Answer (score 0):

**partial answer**

For the first part of your question, regarding this line:

```
chkAktivan.Checked = aktivan == "Da" ? true : false;
```

Try changing it to:

```
chkAktivan.Checked = (aktivan == "Da" ? true : false);
```

OR MORE SIMPLY:

```
chkAktivan.Checked = "Da".Equals(aktivan);
```